# Apache camel bindy

Tags: apache-camel, bindy

I would like to know about writing Objects to a CSV using camel bindy,But my class has a user defined datatypes.I see bindy source code, gives exception for the data types other than which are predefined,Any option in bindy for doing like this.If @Link could help here ?
Thank you :)

here is my class

```
@CsvRecord
Public class Myclass{
@DataField(pos = 1)
 private RefClass refOne;
@DataField(pos = 2)
 private String createdOn; 
}

public class RefClass{
private RefClassTwo refTwo;
private String createdBy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Link can help to encapsulate two related fiends on a separate class.
So, for example for the CSV

Order,Name,Surname

1,Frank,Smith

You could do something like this

```
public class Order {

@DataField(pos = 1)
private int orderNr;
@Link
private Client client;
}

@Link
public class Client {
@DataField(pos = 2)
private String firstname;
@DataField(pos = 3)
private String lastname;
}
```

For a full example of @Link check this [unit test](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-bindy/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/dataformat/bindy/csv/BindyComplexCsvUnmarshallTest.java) from the camel bindy component tests using this complex [model](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-bindy/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/dataformat/bindy/model/complex/twoclassesandonelink)

If you want to get information from one field of the csv to more than one field types in your classes use bindy to parse the information in a String

```
@CsvRecord
Public class Myclass{
@DataField(pos = 1)
 private String refOne;
@DataField(pos = 2)
 private String createdOn; 
}
```

and afterwards use a processor  in your route, parse the content of position 1 and generate the datatypes you want.

Answer (score 0):

Objects linked with `@Link` help to group attributes. But also these linked classes must be Bindy annotated.